# Common interface for Struct of Arrays and Array of Structs in C/C++

Tags: c++

Structure of Arrays (SoA), Arrays of Structs (AoS), and Structure of Array of Structs (SoAoS) are common memory layout patterns that may optimize cache usage and vectorization.
Having used SoA and AoS in C++ I wondered if there exists a good way to hide the internal layout from the user while providing a powerful, common interface that works with the different memory layouts (i.e., convenient iterators or (close to) container like read and write access). Can someone point me to a good implementation or give compelling reasons why this is currently not easily possible in current C++ versions?

Comment: I dont really understand the question. Yes it is easily possible. What problems do you encounter? Maybe you can give some example code?

Comment: A problem is that the very usage pattern changes are what make one or the other faster;

Comment: To add a link to my own question: there indeed attempts to create a common interface though I don't understand all implications. E.g. take a look at  [Wrapping SoA](https://github.com/Yamahari/struct_array) to see where we are with e.g. C20

Comment: Another link https://github.com/crosetto/SoAvsAoS.

Answer (score 1):

As efficiency matters, what you will want to do is enable the same algorithm to run on both AoS and SoA data without changing the algorithm, but probably with rebuilding as we want zero overhead at runtime.

AoS permits getting a structure of fields by index.  To emulate this in SoA dedine a record_ref:

```
struct record_ref{
  int& x, &y;
};
```

this acts very much like

```
struct record {
  int x,y;
};
```

with a few exceptions (like `auto` behaviour).  If needed those can be patched over (delete copy ctor in _ref in SoA, and return a no-copy derived record in AoS, whike enabling copy-to-record and from in both) if you care.

We then do something similar for per-field access.  Create an iterator with compile time stride between elements:

```
template<class T, class Stride>
struct array_it{
  T* ptr=0;
};
```

it should compile down to a raw pointer when `Stride` is `std::integral_constant<std::ptrdiff_t, sizeof(T)>`, which is used in the SoA case.

For the AoS, you use `sizeof(record)` for the stride between elements.

Now alorithms that walk over a given field work on both styles.

---

Now the problem with this solution.  This only makes slow code easier to write, in that iterating over a single field in AoS is slow, and visiting every member of a "struct" is slow in SoA.

This does have some benefit, because you can first write the code slow, test correctness, change layout to see how much faster it gets, etc.  And sometimes some slow memory access cannot be avoided, making it easy has some benefit.

Without reflection and reification (coming in C++20 I hope), I do not know of a way to automate this process.